# Cerrar sesion en mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

tengo el siguiente código para un log

```
Response.Cookies["correoRepresentante"].Value = CorreoL;
Response.Cookies["correoRepresentante"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
Response.Cookies["passRepresentante"].Value = contrasena;
Response.Cookies["passRepresentante"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
```

y para el logout:

```
var c = new HttpCookie("correoRepresentante");
c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(c);

var p = new HttpCookie("passRepresentante");
p.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
Response.Cookies.Add(p);
Response.Cookies.Clear();
Session.Clear();
return View("log");
```

pero luego vuelvo a poner cualquier cosa en el log y entra en la sesión que tenia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que comentas entiendo que la sesión la está liberando bien y que el problema puede estar en la validación que haces con los datos que vienen en la variable de sesión. En cualquier caso te recomiendo usar también `Cookies.Remove(Nombrecookie)` y `Session.Abandon()`.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: El cookies.remove no lo reconoce el visual, dice que cookies no existe en el contexto actual

Comment: Hombre no sería tan cual lo he puesto: en tu ejemplo  quedaría algo como: ‘Response.Cookies.Remove(nombre de la cookie)‘.

Answer (score 1):

Si utilizas **FormsAuthentication** te recomiendo usar:

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon();
    return RedirectToAction("index", "login");
}
```

Si utilizas **OWIN Authentication** te recomiendo usar **solo una** de las siguientes:

```
Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();

Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Comment: Solo estoy usando lo que mostre, solo cookies

Comment: En tu archivo de configuración debes tener un tag como este `<authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>` Ahí se indica el tipo de autenticación que usas, si dice Forms, el primer ejemplo que puse te debería funcionar

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a cambiar esta línea:

```
c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
```

por:

```
c.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
```

Cuando creas el cookie le estas añadiendo 1 año para expirar y al momento de cerrar la sesión solo le estas quitando un día.